# Is Seam Page Action executed in a Postback Request?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

For an initial request, JSF only passes the `Restore View` and `Render Response` phases. The Seam Page Action can be executed before `Render Response` phase during the initial request. Does the Page Action execute normally if there's a post-back request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose by setting the following attribute..

```
<action execute="#{actions.pageAction}" on-postback="false"/>
```